# Integrate an editable pdf in php/cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdf

I am developing an application in cakephp in which I want to integrate an editable pdf. I want the user to fill that pdf and when he/she completes filling it, the document is mailed to his email id and my email id. Please suggest me some way of doing this since I am very new to working with cakephp. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can let users download this PDF or can add button on it as well. Upon clicking button just as an simple ajax you can submit the data to server(All by javascript XMLHTTP).

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. Can you provide me with some links that may help me in learning how to do this?

Comment: When you create PDF You have to give names to each field jst as you give in HTML FORMS. And then you can use script to get and post them. You can find many on google. as [This link](http://www.eformsfactory.com/using-javascript-enhance-pdf-eforms/)  . If you need to fill some data with PHP too, then you would need to create FDF DATA and use some tools to mearge FDF Dada into blank template PDF(which is on Server by tools like PDFTK) And then let user download resulting PDF.